# React Native: optimizing list of items

Tags: performance, react-native, dom, optimization

I have a list of items, each having a *body* and a *source*. Currently it renders like this:

```
const ListItem = (props) => {
    const {body, source} = props.context;

    return (
        <View style={styles.item}>>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}}>
                <Text style={styles.body}>{body}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'lightyellow'}}>
                <Text style={styles.source}>{source}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

That's a lot of nesting and containers. Could it be done more optimally?

Comment: I guess it depends on your design, AFAIK this is fine within React Native assuming you're using an optimized way of rendering your list (e.g. using a FlatList or similar)

Comment: @Dan All external optimizations like FlatList are in place. I am just curious is there a way to skip such a monstrous tree of views or is it ok to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to post my comment as an answer.

Previous comment:

> I guess it depends on your design, AFAIK this is fine within React Native assuming you're using an optimized way of rendering your list (e.g. using a FlatList or similar)

As per your following comment, I don't think it's *monstrous* at all.

Here's an alternative. However, for readability I would much prefer the snippet you posted in your question.

```
const ListItem = props => {
  const items = [
    { key: 'body', backgroundColor: 'lightblue' },
    { key: 'source', backgroundColor: 'lightyellow' }
  ];
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      {
        items.map(({ key, backgroundColor }) => 
          <View style={{ backgroundColor }}>
            <Text style={styles[key]}>
              { props[key] }
            </Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Text component does take backgroundColor so you can let go of the two Views:

```
    <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={[styles.body, {backgroundColor: '...'}]}>{body}</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.source, {backgroundColor: '...'}]}>{source}</Text>
    </View>
```

Additionally, I don't know what the styles.item consists of, but if you want to go all the way, you might replace the other container View with React.Fragment.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this code isn't equal to the source -- texts would go one *after* another and not one *above* another.

Comment: @DenisKulagin are you sure this code isn't equal to the source? Two Text components inside a View will go one above the other for me. incase you want them one after the other just add flexDirection: 'row', to the View style.

Comment: I am new to the React Native so I might be mistaken. I'll check. Thanks for pointing out to it anyway.

Comment: @DenisKulagin np, happy coding!